# Comparing files for their differences

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can print the lines different between two files. But I need to get the difference of each line regardless of their order in the file.
For example in file1, there is line 'hf_clk_div,INPUT'. I want to search this in file 2 and if for example matched line is 'hf_clk_div,OUTPUT' it will find that the difference is INPUT vs OUTPUT. Or find clk_en,INPUT in file 2 but the match line is clk_enable,INPUT it should report this difference as well.

I am using below code for printing line differences

```
f1 = set(open(file1).readlines())

f2 = set(open(file2).readlines())

for line1 in list(f1-f2):

    print(line1, end='')
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand it correctly, could you provide two minimal files including expected vs. actual result? You might want to refer to [mcve] when asking for debugging help.

Comment: Check python's built-in [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)

Comment: half_clock_division?

Comment: make your question a little bit clear!

Comment: See whether f1.intersection(f2)  and  f1.difference(f2) may be of use. Also: common = f1.intersection(f2); f1_only = f1.difference(common)  etc.